# ng-repeat using Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do an `ng-repeat` on some JSON I have imported into Firebase. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="place in places">
  <h3>{{ place.title }}</h3>
</div>
```

I've also got variable called `placesRef` which is pointing to a child of my Firebase object called `places`, and when I load up the page the `console.log` prints out the objects.

```
var placesRef = new Firebase(FBURL).child('places');

placesRef.once('value', function (snap) {
  var places = snap.val();
  console.log(places);
});
```

What I would like to know, is how can I get that ng-repeat to work, so I can print out the objects on the page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to get 3-way binding to work or just get it to display? var places = snap.val(); looks like it should be $scope.places = snap.val(); if that's in your controller. If it's not could you make a plunker so we can better understand what is going on?

Comment: @rtucker88 I'm just trying to get it to display. I get the error `$scope is not defined.`

Comment: Can you make a plunker? I need more information.

Comment: @rtucker88 I've made a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/M7OGgeG2lA1pq3PCm89p?p=preview I'm trying to get that `ng-repeat` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a plunker using 3-way binding at http://plnkr.co/MT6aHhAFMiYA9t9pHVW9. This gives you 3-way binding which is one of the big selling points of Firebase. Here's the relevant code:

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/data');
var childRef = rootRef.child('users');
var syncChild = $firebase(childRef);

var syncObj = syncChild.$asObject();
syncObj.$bindTo($scope, "users");
```

We use the ref and bring it into Angularfire through $firebase(childRef). We then tell Angularfire to treat the reference as an object and finally set up 3-way binding with syncObj.$bindTo.